# Cypress how to break from a nested if loop

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, conditional-statements, cypress

I want to come out of a nested if loop provided a particular condition is met. Below is the snippet:-

```
  cy.get(A).then(()=>{
  do{
        cy.get(B).each(()=>{
            switch(C){
                 case "1":
                       if(some condition){
                          this.method1()
                          return false //THIS IS NOT BREAKING THE OUTERMOST THEN LOOP !!!!!
                       }
                       method2()
                       break
                 case "2":
                       if(some condition){
                          this.method3()
                          return false
                        }
                       method4()
                       break

            } //switch ends

            If(method1 is executed){
                  Flag= true
                  return False // THIS IS NOT Breaking the for each here
             }

        }) //each ends

         If(flag==true){
               Cy.get().click()
         }

    }while(someCondition) //do while ends

}) //Then ends
```

How do I break out from the switch case 1 if method1 is executed ??

Comment: do you want the test to throw an error or just to continue the other code?

Comment: I would start by nesting the do/wihile loop in a cy command callback since it is sinchronous in an async environment. Also do a console log on the conditional variables - on the lines that are failing to stop the code, since it is most likely the entire If statement is not being executed.

Another important thing - DO/while loop executes at least once even if the condition to stop is valid - so I do not recommend using it.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov I want this loop to execute at least once. Hence the do while. To answer your first question -- I do not want to throw an error i just simply want to terminate all loops if my condition is met. Can you elaborate more on "nesting the do/wihile loop in a cy command callback"

Comment: If I need sycn code in my cypress tests i use a chain like: `cy.log('doWhileLoop').then(()=>{ ///Code }` . Also If you need to store conditional variables - store them in an array or object, or allias because cypress doesnt store things in let/const variables. Actualy the problem is more for the storage of the conditional variable, then the nesting inn this case

Comment: @RosenMihaylov I am close to solving this problem just need to figure out how to repeat my for each multiple times depending on a conditional variable in its then clause:
//Need to repeat the forEach again if flag=true. How to achieve this ??
foreach(()=>{
  // some code here
}).then(()=>{
  if(some condition) {var flag=true}
  else { flag=false}
})

Comment: Seems like a good idea if you return the conditional value at the end of the forEach. I would do like `.forEach((element)=>{ let conditions = {}; conditions.c1 = element.text; return conditions }.then(conditions => { if (condition.c1) { //code} else {//some other code}})

Comment: @RosenMihaylov the conditional value will be known in the then clause of for each. Depending onits value i need to repeat my for each. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I suggest this sample recursion as template for you to use:

```
cy.get(A).then((someCondition) => {
    cy.get(B).then(elements => {
        conditionalRecursion()
        function conditionalRecursion(index = 0) {
            if (index >= elements.length) {
                return
            }
            if(someCondition) {
                switch(C){
                    case "1":
                        this.method1()
                        Cy.get().click()
                        break
                    case "2":
                        this.method3()
                        break
                    //Switch cases are supposed to have default case here too
                }
                return
            }
            switch(C){
                case "1":
                    method2()
                    break
                case "2":
                    method4()
                    break
                //Switch cases are supposed to have default case here too
            }
            index++
            return conditionalRecursion(index)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you @RosenMihaylov, I tweaked your sample a bit and the recursion worked for me.